# One element covers another; how can I set the element to appear in front/above so that it isn't hidden/covered/invisible

Tags: css

I have bought some template and added react-select. But for some unknown reason, the select is not displayed correctly.

This is probably some common behavior in CSS. But due to the lack of CSS knowledge, i can't find the right words to describe this kind of situation.

Can someone explain to me why this exactly is happening? I'm guessing it has something to do with priority. Anyhow, could I solve this with some CSS rule? Or are there other things I need to consider on fixing this?

[image]

Comment: You're looking for `z-index`

Comment: @zzzzBov Great that was indeed what I was looking for !!

Comment: @zzzzBov Can you make an answer on this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index?v=example), which lets you specify which elements should be "above" or "below" each other on the z-axis(out of the screen)